# give limitations to the user to add new records into mysql on daily basis

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a app, in which user suppose to click and send images twice in a day,but I dont understand how to do it,I want to give user a limitation that he could send picture twice in a day,not more than that.Assume that 10 rupees is a amount for each record,so it should be 20 rupees per day not more than that.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `daily_uploads` (img_path, geoplugin_city, geoplugin_regionName, date, amount)
VALUES ('$img', '$city', '$region',  '$date','$amount')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

echo"success";

}

else{
    echo"Something wrong";
}
```

Comment: Before loading a new image, which checks for the same day are not already present two record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find out how many entries have been made today with mysql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `daily_uploads` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE();
```

use this info to prohibit inserting in PHP.

Comment: Good answer but bear in mind that to avoid inconsistencies this needs to be implemented at the database level. For example, you mind find someone inserting a row directly into the table using the mysql console. Then the check inside PHP would not be activated and you would have a user with three ore more records.

Comment: The second point is that to avoid race conditions, you need to take a lock on the table. Without locks, it's quite possible that a row maybe inserted by another thread, or the user may hit refresh before the insert has been executed (you never know when the pipe will break) this also leads to inconsistent data

Comment: @e4c5 yes sure, but I would consider an user that has direct access to the mysql database an admin that should know what s/he is doing. and regarding to your answer: one thing I have learned in the past years: always avoid mysql-triggers, never use them. all developers that don't have the trigger in mind won't know what is going on with the database. as a developer you use PHP for a reason - you don't have to force the database to do logical things for you.

Comment: sorry to disagree with you @low_rents you cannot expect a DBA or any other admin to remember (much less know every constraint that has been enforced in PHP) that's not his job. And everyone makes mistakes. It's the job of the developer to make sure that such mistakes don't lead to incorrect results. Secondly there is absolutely no basis for not using triggers on mysql.

Comment: @e4c5 according your second point: this can be easily avoided by using transactions. but this was just my simple answer to a simple question and I think it would be way too much if I included something like this.

Comment: Transactions cannot prevent the inconsistency that i have mentioned!!! it's not just a matter of giving the simplest answer, it's a matter of covering all the bases.

Comment: @e4c5 sorry, but I really can't think of such a strange use case where a DBA would randomly insert data rows into a table. and if another developer works on the same project without knowing about the trigger (maybe years later) then s/he is lost until s/he finds out about the trigger. triggers are hidden monsters because you don't see them in your application - which would be basically the opposite of [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) which is state of the art atm. here a few other reasons why to avoid triggers in most cases: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16162/69693

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, you can only have two records per user. That is normally done using CHECK CONSTRAINTs but unfortunately that's not supported by mysql, so we will have to make use of a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER daily_uploads_check
BEFORE INSERT ON daily_uploads
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM daily_upates WHERE /* conditions here */ ) =2  THEN
    SIGNAL 'your error message'
  END IF 
END
```

You should [aquire locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html) to make sure that no other thread is making an insert the moment after you have executed your select query.