# inserting record into mysql table if column count value is 2

Tags: php, mysql

Below is code for count record for today's date and inserting into database if value is not more than two per day.now problem is I want to insert into database if count for today is below 2.

```
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
$region = $geo["geoplugin_regionName"];
$img = $_POST['img'];
$amount = 5;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `daily_uploads` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 2) {

    echo"already exist";
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 


} else {


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `daily_uploads` (img, geoplugin_city, geoplugin_regionName, amount)
   VALUES ('$img', '$city', '$region','$amount')";
         // echo "success";
}
```

Comment: you are not insert the second query on db because you haven't execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to execute the insert $sql string, you can do it this way:

```
if ($conn->query($sql)) {
     echo ('success');
} else {
     echo ('error');
}
```

Comment: its inserting now but one issue is there ,count for todays entry is already tow in database but still it executes the insert query,what i want is it should not add entry if record has added twice for todays date

Comment: reffer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120323/give-limitations-to-the-user-to-add-new-records-into-mysql-on-daily-basis?noredirect=1#comment69446787_41120323