# inserting record if count of column is less than two else not inserting into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

just want to add record if count of column is less than 2 for today's date and if count is more than two it should not get insert into the db.It's keep getting added after two records.

```php
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
$region = $geo["geoplugin_regionName"];
$img = $_POST['img'];
$amount = 5;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalupload FROM `daily_uploads` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()";


$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql); 
$sum = $row['totalupload'];

if ($sum < 2 ) { 
     $sql = "INSERT INTO `daily_uploads` (img, geoplugin_city, geoplugin_regionName, amount)
   VALUES ('$img', '$city', '$region','$amount')";
     if ($conn->query($sql)) {
     echo ('success');
} else {
     echo ('error');
}

} else {

  echo"already exist";
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing OOP with procedural. Also `mysql_*` is deprecated and removed as of PHP7 use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead

Comment: How many times you will ask same question again and again?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @rahul see my previous question was about executing insert query properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137765/inserting-record-into-mysql-table-if-column-count-value-is-2?noredirect=1#comment69478710_41137765   this time i am asking what is wrong in my code why my insert query still working even there is two records available for today date

Comment: @Rahul why I will ask same question ,look carefully what was i asking in previous and in this

Comment: Assuming 'date' is a 'Date' field, you can simplify the query: `date = CURDATE()`. If not you can do a between, but you'll have to format the two times to `Y-m-d 00:00:00` and `Y-m-d 23:59:59`

Comment: Can you also add the table structure(s) for this particular query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the connection after count query like this,

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this one hope it will help you.

    $user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    $geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
    $city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
    $region = $geo["geoplugin_regionName"];
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $amount = 5;

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalupload FROM `daily_uploads` WHERE   DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()";
    $qry= mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
   $count = $row['totalupload'];
    if ($count < 2 ) { 
         $sql = "INSERT INTO `daily_uploads` (img, geoplugin_city, geoplugin_regionName, amount)
       VALUES ('$img', '$city', '$region','$amount')";
         if ($conn->query($sql)) {
         echo ('success');
    } else {
         echo ('error');
    }

    } else {

      echo"already exist";
```

Comment: Nope, not only is this slower it also makes the wrong assumption ($count is always 1 in your example)

Comment: mysql_num_rows will give the count of records fetched from the database

Comment: I'll briefly explain: It's always one, because in the query COUNT(*)  is used (you should NEVER use * in a COUNT though)... With or without GROUP BY it will return just 1 row...